# Why am I getting an EitherT type error?

Tags: haskell, heist

When I try loading my Heist (0.11) templates with this function:

```
load :: MonadIO n => FilePath -> [(Text, Splice n)] -> IO (HeistState n)
load baseDir splices = do
    tmap <- runEitherT  $ do
        templates <- loadTemplates baseDir
        let hc = HeistConfig [] defaultLoadTimeSplices splices [] templates
        initHeist hc
    either (error . concat) return tmap
```

I get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `EitherT e0 m0 t0'
            with actual type `either-3.1:Control.Monad.Trans.Either.EitherT
                                [String] IO Heist.TemplateRepo'
In the return type of a call of `loadTemplates'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: templates <- loadTemplates baseDir
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `do { templates <- loadTemplates baseDir;
        let hc
              = HeistConfig [] defaultLoadTimeSplices splices [] templates;
        initHeist hc }'
```

To me, `loadTemplate` seems to be returning the expected type, except with the type parameters filled in with concrete types. What am I missing?

Comment: This looks like a broken package setup - notice how it refers to a type by a particular package version?  That is a strong indicator that you have a Dependency problem.

Comment: The imports used for `load` and the imports used for `loadTemplates` are getting `EitherT` from different definitions in different modules or versions or packages.

Comment: This happens in cases where there are multiple versions of the same package installed.  Use ghc-pkg to remove all but one version of the either package, then reinstall and try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in cases where there are multiple versions of the same package installed.  Use ghc-pkg to remove all but one version of the `either` package, then reinstall and try it again.

I've been puzzled by this time and time again.  When the types are right and you start to think it's a GHC bug, check for duplicate packages.